# Terminal does not seem to have reverse-i-search (ctrl-r does nothing)

Tags: linux, search, terminal

I'm ssh-ing into a remote machine and when I try to search my history in a linux terminal with reverse-i-search, nothing happens. I press ctrl-r as I usually do on my machine, but the prompt doesn't appear.

Any ideas? How can I check the keybindings for ctrl-r? How do I set them if they aren't set? Do I have to apt-get reverse-i-search functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use ctrl-r your shell needs to be using readline (or something similar), your history should be collected.

- So you should verify your shell for example `sh` doesn't support this.
- You should check it the history is collected. For example with bash shell: `echo $HISTFILE`

I think these can be the main reasons.

Hopefully with simply entering `bash`, you can switch to a proper shell which will support this.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that highlighted my ignorance of linux (i.e. the difference between `sh` and `bash`) and leads me to another question. When I ssh into a remote machine, what am I looking at on the terminal? It's not `sh` or `bash`, so what is it?

Comment: I think I answered my own question. It depends on the specific machine and what preferences are set. I used the `echo $SHELL` command and got /bin/tcsh. I guess `tcsh` is also a shell?

Comment: Yes it is. You can test if there is bash installed on the system with typing `bash`, and hopefully a new shell will be started. If not then you have to ask the system administrator to install it. Maybe zsh also worth a try.